# How do I create an mp4 file from a collection of H.264 frames and audio frames?

Tags: audio, video, h.264, mp4

I have a program that captures and stores H.264 encoded video as well as audio into a proprietary format file. I need to be able to export that video and audio to an mp4 file. I prefer C# but will use C++ if necessary. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

To produce MPEG-4 Part 14 `.MP4` file you need a multiplexer. There is a choice of multiplexers out there:

- [FFmpeg (libavformat)](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-November/002967.html)
- DirectShow filters (free and open source from [GDCL](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/index.htm), commercial)
- [Windows 7+ Media Foundation file sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

API and complexity might vary because some of multiplexers are expected to be a part of pipeline, they are not completely standalone classes. You might want to check respective samples (and license agreements, perhaps, too) to see what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at libmp4v2. Fairly straightforward to use..

http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/